# How can I pass a varying number of parameters to a function, as opposed to accepting a varying number of paramters?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm aware that you can use a plain Javascript object to accept a varying number of parameters, like so:

```
function f(params) {
  // do something with params.param1
  // do something with params.param2
  // etc...
}

function t() {
  f({param1: "a", param2: 22, param3: [1,2,3]});  // 3 parameters
  f({param1: 'st'});  // 1 parameter
}
```

But how can you write a function that calls another function and passes an acceptable number of parameters without knowing in advance how many parameters that function accepts?

For example,

```
// func is a function object, params is a container of some kind that holds the parameters that that function would accept
function pass_to_func(func, params) {
  func(params);  // func can be anything, which means it can accept any number of params, depending on context
}
```

I tried this:

```
function pass_to_func(func, params) {
  func(params.join());  // params is an array of parameters, but this doesn't work 
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, but please keep in mind that it has to be supported in [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), since that's the environment I'm dealing with.

Comment: In Javascript, the number of params is not enforced. You could pass 10 params to a function that only defines 1 and it will not throw any errors. You can call a function that accepts 3 params without providing any params and it will not throw any compile or runtime errors. Those params will simply be `undefined`

Comment: In essence, it is up to the function itself to handle any number of, or undefined parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
// if params is an array
function pass_to_func(func, params) {
  func.apply(null, params);
}

// if params is not an array
function pass_to_func(func, params) {
  func.call(null, params);
}
```

Comment: Cool! I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Pass an object to the function.

```
function myFunction(obj){
  console.log(obj.color);
}

    var myobj = {
        color:'brown',
        smells:'bad'

    };

myfuntion(myObj);
```

Comment: this isn't going to work because the functions that are called are not written to handle object parameters. I need to take the parameters out of the container and pass them individually to the called function.

Comment: What do you mean by "not written to handle object parameters". If it's written in javascript the function can certainly  handle an object as a parameter since EVERYTHING in javascript is an object.

Comment: You could also do a boolean `typeof` test and carry forward from there. But there isn't any limit on what a function can take in. The internal logic will handle it.

Comment: There are lots of other functions that can be called. If it can be helped, I'm trying to find a way to pass a variable number of parameters to some function rather than rewrite each and every function to accept and handle an object. So what I'm saying is: I prefer to "unwrap" the parameters from the container I mentioned in my post and pass these individually, rather than pass all the parameters wrapped up into a single object, because then I'd need to rewrite every such function to unwrap that object upon receiving it.