# How can I pass an Apps Script function value to another function and have it invoked there?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750020/how-can-i-pass-a-varying-number-of-parameters-to-a-function-as-opposed-to-accep?noredirect=1#comment84501437_48750207), I've been able to invoke generic functions with any number of parameters. But as I was further refining my code, I came across this problem:

```
function test() {
  var object = {to: "test@domain.com", subject: "subject line", body: "using object"};
  var attributes = ["test@domain.com", "subject line", "using attributes"];
  pass_to_func1(MailApp.sendEmail, attributes); 
  pass_to_func2(MailApp.sendEmail, object);
}

function pass_to_func1(func, attributes) {
  try {
    func.apply(null, attributes);
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    return;
  }
  Logger.log("pass_to_func1 success");
}

function pass_to_func2(func, object) {
  try {
    func.call(null, object);
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    return;
  }
  Logger.log("pass_to_func2 success");
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass the [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) funtion value as an argument to a "middle-man" function, of which I have two versions.

One invokes the function parameter with `Function.prototype.apply` with an array of strings as its argument (send-to email, subject, body).

The other invokes the function parameter with `Function.prototype.call` with a javascript object as its argument (see the MailApp developer reference for more info).

Both of them throw the same error, shown below:

> InternalError: Method "sendEmail" was invoked with [object Object] as "this" value that can not be converted to type MailApp.

I don't know how to make sense of an error like that and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Look up Function::call and Function::apply in MDN's javascript reference. You probably haven't 'scoped' the function call to the right object (which I suspect should be MailApp in this case)

Comment: I actually just figured this out as well! Thank you for helping anyway, you were right on

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured out what the problem is.

I needed to replace

`func.apply(null, attributes);` and `func.call(null, object);`

with

```
func.apply(MailApp, attributes);
```

and `func.call(MailApp.object);`